# How to align column content when scrollbars applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a situation when some data is being displayed in different columns. This listing has 2 parts.

1. Listing Head
2. Listing Body

Body section will have a `max-height`. When there will be more content that can fit this height then scrollbars will be applied automatically.

Now the issue is this when scroll bars are applied, then alignment of the content in Head and body sections disturbs and looks weird.

Is there any possible solution to fix this issue in css, JavaScript, jQuery or any other way i.e content should align automatically in head and body section when scrollbars are applied?

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.listing {
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.col-1,
.col-2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 40%;
}

.col-1 + .col-1,
.col-1 + .col-2,
.col-2 + .col-2,
.col-2 + .col-1 {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.listing-body {
  height: 95px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>Listing with correct alignment</h2>
<div class="listing">
  <div class="listing-header row">
    <div class="col-1">Heading 1</div>
    <div class="col-1">Heading 2</div>
    <div class="col-2">Heading 3</div>
    <div class="col-1">Heading 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">Data 1</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 2</div>
      <div class="col-2">Data 3</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">Data 1</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 2</div>
      <div class="col-2">Data 3</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">Data 1</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 2</div>
      <div class="col-2">Data 3</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">Data 1</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 2</div>
      <div class="col-2">Data 3</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">Data 1</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 2</div>
      <div class="col-2">Data 3</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Listing with Incorrect alignment</h2>
<div class="listing">
  <div class="listing-header row">
    <div class="col-1">Heading 1</div>
    <div class="col-1">Heading 2</div>
    <div class="col-2">Heading 3</div>
    <div class="col-1">Heading 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">Data 1</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 2</div>
      <div class="col-2">Data 3</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">Data 1</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 2</div>
      <div class="col-2">Data 3</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">Data 1</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 2</div>
      <div class="col-2">Data 3</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">Data 1</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 2</div>
      <div class="col-2">Data 3</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">Data 1</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 2</div>
      <div class="col-2">Data 3</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">Data 1</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 2</div>
      <div class="col-2">Data 3</div>
      <div class="col-1">Data 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add 15px padding-right or margin-right to listing-header when scroll-bar applies

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution but how can we detect that when scroll bars are applied?

Comment: Jquery is having one function called hasScrollBar(). for eg $('#my_div').hasScrollBar(). It returns true if it has scroll bar.

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution I don't wants to rely on a function to check for scrollbars each minute. Is there any way or event that informs the browser when scroll bars are applied?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a class to compensate for the scrollbar with a margin; for example:

`.ScrollBarCompensate{margin-right:15px;}`

And then use JQuery to apply this class when scrollbar is present

`$('.ScrollBarCompensate').hasScrollBar(); //returns true if scrollbar is present`

Then you can either add the class like so:

`$( ".listing" ).addClass( "ScrollBarCompensate" );`

Or alternatively, don't create the CSS class and just write inline CSS to whatever you like within the scroll bar `if` statement:

`$(this).css('margin-right', "15px !important");`